# Installing updates froze virtual machine

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, virtualbox, update-manager

I was just installing updates for 10.10 amd_64 Ubuntu desktop guest system, but the system seems to have frozen while applying changes, going into host-F1 terminals doesn't work.

If I do a hard reset of the virtual machine, what sort of manteinance/recovery operation should I do? Any apt-get commands I should do to rollback the installation/obtain more info of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to recover a virtual machine is to make use of the snapshot feature available in VirtualBox. As far as apt-get, you can try `apt-get check`, which will make sure none of your packages are *broken*--i.e. missing dependencies. It there are any, you can use `apt-get --fix-broken install` to allow apt to try to automagically fix it. In the worst case, `apt-get remove <pkg-name>` any broken packages, and try to reinstall them via `apt-get install <pkg-name>`. In the *very* worst case, you might have to use `dpkg --remove <pkg-name` if apt cannot remove them for some reason.

NB: This is just a quick synopsis; it cannot instil wisdom or avert impending experience.